# Lambda - EnvironmentVariablesFeature is not supported in cn-north-1 region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy lambda using the serverless framework in China AWS region - I am getting into below error.

Is there any workaround to pass variables in serverless.yaml?

```
CloudFormation - UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - aws-china-lambda-Test-Env Serverless: Operation failed! Serverless: View the full error output: https://cn-north-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=cn-north-1#/stack/detail?stackId=arn%3Aaws-cn%3Acloudformation%3Acn-north-1%XXXXX%3Astack%2Faws-china-lambda-Test-Env%2Fc9228230-72e5-11e9-a846-XXXX Serverless 

Error --------------------------------------- 

An error occurred: QueueAlertLambdaFunction - EnvironmentVariablesFeature is not supported in cn-north-1 region. For more information, please visit the AWS Lambda documentation on Environment Variables. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: a19ca4e3-XXX-11e9-adef-XXXXX).
```

Comment: If you temporarily remove the Lambda function from the serverless YAML, re-deploy the stack, then add the Lambda function back in, and re-deploy again, does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 11/19/2019** It is now supported see [AWS Lambda now supports Environment Variables in the AWS China (Beijing) Region, operated by Sinnet, and the AWS China (Ningxia) Region, operated by NWCD](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-now-supports-environment-variables-in-the-aws-china-beijing-region-operated-by-sinnet-and-the-aws-china-ningxia-region-operated-by-nwcd/)

---

This is indeed a limitation in the China regions (see [AWS Lambda](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/aws/latest/userguide/lambda.html)):

> The AWS services in China implementation of AWS Lambda is unique in the following ways:
>
> - The following AWS Lambda features are unavailable in the Beijing and Ningxia Regions:
>
>   - Lambda environment variables

One way to solve your problem is to use old serverless plugins that used to offer a solution for environment variables before this feature was available in Lambda, have a look at those:

- [serverless-plugin-write-env-vars](https://github.com/silvermine/serverless-plugin-write-env-vars)
- [serverless-dotenv-plugin](https://github.com/colynb/serverless-dotenv-plugin)
- [serverless-env-generator](https://github.com/DieProduktMacher/serverless-env-generator)